# SSAS 2012 cube browser- how can I create columns from dimensions?

Tags: ssas, cube, dimension

I am new to SSAS, and have created a cube in SSAS 2012.

When I browse the cube, I can easily at my dimensions as rows, but how do I add them as columns? In previous versions (I have access to a Cube created in 2008), when you browse the cube, you can drag dimensions into either columns or rows.

Have I setup my cube incorrectly?

Answer (score 8):

In short: you can't any more, because the feature is no longer available. [According to Chris Webb](http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/whats-new-in-analysis-services-2012-multidimensional/):

> The cube browser has now disappeared from SSDT, and is replaced by the
>   control used by the SSRS query generator. This is because the old
>   browser used the OWC control which was deprecated years ago and
>   finally had to be replaced; it’s a massive step backwards because this
>   control is truly awful: for example you can no longer put anything
>   other than Measures on columns in your query.

You can confirm this by changing to design mode, and creating a simple MDX query with a dimension on the Columns axis:

```
SELECT
[Geography].[Country].[Country] ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

If I run this query in the SSAS browser, I get the error

> Query preparation failed: ...The first axis [should not] reference any
>   dimension other than the Measures dimension"

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean the cube browser in BIDS/Visual Studio?  This is generally a waste of time: it has poor functionality and regularly returns results that differ from other tools.

You would be better off using the same client tool your end users use.  Excel 2010 / 2013 is pretty good.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question, and would have been better suited as a comment.

Comment: Well my friend, 6 days have passed and no-one else has come up with any better answers.  As you say, you are "new to SSAS", I have 7 years experience with it.  I'd still say my recommendation is the best path to follow.

Comment: Mike, I wasn't having a go. I was simply saying that this doesn't quite answer my question. I am aware of Excel and how to use it for my purpose, my question was more based around where the cube browser has gone, and hence why I suggested your answer was better suited as a comment.